Could we implement a spam filter?
We've been seeing a lot of spam like this lately. I've been flagging all of them, but it's still annoying to see them on the front page. Is there some way to put in regex filters to combat this sort of thing?

We have one implemented, and we've adjusted the black list accordingly. The issue is that this is coming from a vast number of large networks, so it's taking a while to stop. 
I'm going to be modifying Bitcoin's setting in our global spam shield so that your flags (and moderators destroying these obvious spammers) block these even faster. I raised it a bit before the weekend, but I can take it a bit higher comfortably. 
Now, FAIR WARNING ... (for all)
If someone leaves an answer like this:

The best I've seen is FooCoin (http://foocoin.com)

... that consists of barely more than a link, it's probably going to be deleted very quickly. If you're a new user leaving such answers, you might find your account removed.
Additionally, questions that seek recommendations for third-party tools or services that do not provide a very narrow criteria that limits the number of answers are probably going to be closed very quickly, because those are precisely the kinds of answers that they attract. 
This is exactly the kind of thing that attracts this sort of spam, so we need our default quality to be much higher than what the spammers want to contribute in order for it to stand out. 
